# How to check cabal flags in a sandbox

Tags: haskell, cabal

I can do `cabal install --enable-executable-profiling`. `cabal` is supposed to remember the flag `cabal.config` file. However, I'm using a sandbox and I can't find any **config** file. How can I find which flags have been activated ?

Answer (score 1):

When you create a sandbox with `cabal sandbox init` a default config file `cabal.sandbox.config` is created. Create a new file `cabal.config` in the same directory and edit it according to your needs, e.g. in your case add a line

```
executable-profiling: True
```

Comment: Please don't do that, just create a new file with that line.

Comment: Are you saying that each time I call `cabal configure` the `cabal.sandbox.config` file is modified according to the given flags ?

Comment: @MikhailGlushenkov Thanks, I've misread the comment at the top of `cabal.sandbox.config`. So `cabal` will read both files if present?

Comment: @kaoskorobase Yes, `cabal.sandbox.config` is for internal stuff and `cabal.config` is for user settings.

Comment: That's still doesn't answer my question. My question is not how to override manually the cabal configuration, but where does cabal store automatic configuration ?

Comment: `cabal install` stores the package configuration ([LocalBuildInfo](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Cabal-1.20.0.2/docs/Distribution-Simple-LocalBuildInfo.html)) in `dist/dist-sandbox-HASH/setup-config`, `cabal configure` stores it in `dist/setup-config`.